# Aligning data in a table according to each characteristics in php

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I get data from a mssql database that I want to display in a table.
The table has three categories:
ORDER NUMBER
PAYMENT STATUS
ORDER STATUS

The problem is as follows:
I would like to align my order numbers with the payment status and the order status in order to have a nice table that is well aligned.

Here is my code in php and the result it gives me :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/clientsS.css">
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="BLOC1">
    <div class="NUMBER">
        <center><table>
            <tr>
                <th>NUMERO COMMANDE</th>
                <th>STATUT PAIEMENT</th>
                <th>STATUT COMMANDE</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><?php
            //CONNEXION ODBC SERVER//
            $dsn="";
            $user="";
            $password="";
            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn
                ,$user, $password);

            //REQUETES
            $sql = <<<EOF
                    SELECT top 10 [enc_cmd_num]
                    FROM [encaissement]
                    WHERE enc_date= '20221220'
                    EOF;

            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
            

            while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)){ 
                echo $resultrow["enc_cmd_num"]."<br/>" ; }
                ?>

            </td>
        </div>

        <div class="TITRE">

            <td><?php
            //CONNEXION ODBC SERVER//
            $dsn="";
            $user="";
            $password="";
            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);

            //REQUETES
            $sql = <<<EOF
                    SELECT top 10 [enc_paye]
                    FROM [encaissement]
                    WHERE enc_date= '20221220'
                    EOF;

            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

            //CONDITION
                while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)) {
                    switch($resultrow['enc_paye']){
                    case 0:
                        echo "<p>En attente paiement</p> \r\n";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        echo "<p class='green'>Commande payée<p/>\r\n";
                        break;
                }

            }
?>
</td>
                <td><?php
            //CONNEXION ODBC SERVER//
            $dsn="";
            $user="";
            $password="";
            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);

            //REQUETES
            $sql = <<<EOF
                    SELECT top 10 [enc_prepared]
                    FROM [encaissement]
                    WHERE enc_date= '20221220'
                    EOF;

            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

            //CONDITION

                while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)) {
                    switch($resultrow['enc_prepared']){
                    case 0:
                        echo "<p>Commande en attente</p> \r\n";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        echo "<p class='yellow'>Commande en cours de préparation<p/>\r\n";
                        break;

                }

            }



?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

[image: SCREEN OF THE RESULT]

Comment: 1. Fetch the data from the database _once_ (just get all the columns you need in one single query). 2. Iterate through the data and add one `<tr>` (table row) _per record_ to your table. There are plenty of sites explaining what tables are for, how to use them and how display data from a database in them.

Comment: You also have some `<div>` and `</div>` between your `</td><td>`, which is not allowed in HTML

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is preferable that you use the same tag `<p>` even for the first `<td>`:

Test it like this and tell me if it works for you:

```
echo "<p>".$resultrow["enc_cmd_num"]."<p/>" ;
```

Instead of:

```
echo $resultrow["enc_cmd_num"]."<br/>" ;
```

Comment: This is _not_ a good answer. This has the same big flaws as the original (querying the database several times instead of fetching all columns at once) and are also using HTML tables completely wrong. There are also have some `<div>` and `</div>` between your `</td><td>`, which is not allowed in HTML.